# How to alter the database from within a Ruby on Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

is it possible to alter the database from within a Rails Application?

I am translating a Java routine that was executed every 3 hours to Rails which does the following:
It reads data from a website. This data  is stored in a temporary table in the database. After reading is finished, the table of the older data is dropped and the temporary table renamed.

Is it possible to do that with Ruby on Rails?

Comment: @RoRNewbiew -- if my answer worked, or didn't, please comment (or mark as correct)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute arbitrary sql:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("drop temp_table")
```